# A ton of Wordpress questions on SO

Tags: discussion, feature-request, wordpress-se

I've commented on at least four WordPress related posts on Stack Overflow tonight only that don't even remotely belong to SO. Some belong nowhere since some users believe we'll just build WordPress for them.

I think SO should automatically suggest users to move the question to WordPress if it detects WordPress in title or tags or maybe even the text. Somewhat like the 'Similar Questions' and 'Questions that may already have your answer' work only that it should be in big bold red or something. I don't know what would work for this kind of users, but something needs to be done.

Comment: `since some users believe we'll just build Wordpress for them` -- Gee, *that's* never happened before.

Comment: I'm not sure about this. Why not just flag?

Comment: @simchona because most of this users probably don't even know that the Wordpress Answers exist.

Comment: If the questions are pure crap anyway, why make them post somewhere else?

Comment: @simchona good point. But surprisingly some actually aren't :P I would just like that SO would expose the existence of Wordpress Answers if it detects the question is wordpress related.

Comment: For now you could just leave a comment on the decent ones, or flag them for migration

Comment: Many Wordpress questions are still perfectly on topic on Stack Overflow. There's no totally clear boundary

Answer (score 5):

Wordpress isn't the worst offender. Only about 2% of wordpress questions get closed as off topic. Seems like a lot of work for a small number of questions that the community can just take care of.

Here's the top 10 worst tags by ratio of how many questions are closed as Off Topic. Limited to tags with at least 20,000 questions.

```
tagname            TagQuestionCount OffTopicCount ratioClosedOffTopic 
------------------ ---------------- ------------- ------------------- 
linux              42919            2137          4.97914676483609    
apache             21386            681           3.18432619470682    
osx                26553            690           2.59857643204158    
windows            42232            933           2.20922523205153    
wordpress          24113            472           1.95745033799195    
facebook           36835            583           1.58273381294964    
algorithm          25420            357           1.40440597954367    
ipad               23311            180           0.772167646175625   
performance        26726            198           0.740851605178478   
sql-server-2008    22374            163           0.728524179851614
```

[Data.SE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/90001/off-topic-posts-by-tag?MinQuestionCount=20000)

Comment: Haha, OK. Tnx! :)

Comment: That only shows how many questions were flagged as off topic and moved by moderations. In reality, the number is much larger. There's no practical way to get hard data, but I've seen plenty of WordPress-specific questions that weren't flagged at all.

Comment: @IanDunn that's not what the query is doing. Its looking for posts that are "Closed as off-topic" That can be the result of a moderation action or a [community action](http://stackoverflow.com/q/884426/119477). The comuunity action ones obviously aren't migrated. I would expect a certain number of questions that should be closed are open and some that were closed that shouldn't be. My only point is that the OS based tags are worse than wordpress, so if you're going to target a tag Wordpress wouldn't be what I would start with

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter why limit the query to tags with less than 20,000 questions? Shouldn't we also care about popular subjects (e.g., Java, C#) with crappy questions?

Comment: @Mureinik I had a inequality direction error in the post but not int the query. I edited the post to clear that up. Thanks for making me aware.